# undefined object of AngularJS form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to enter all the variables of a ng-repeat, now I run into a problem when I enter these variables there are two variables as undefined, and they are not different from the rest, because this happens, the variables are "pies_tablares" and "observacion":

```
<tr ng-repeat="table in datos">
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="especie" ng-value="table.especie" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="largo" ng-value="table.largo" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ancho" ng-value="table.ancho" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="espesor" ng-value="table.espesor" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cantidad" ng-value="table.cantidad" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pies_tablares" ng-value="table.pt" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="observacion">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here always are undefined:

```
angular.forEach($scope.datos, function(obj)
{
dataConcilation = {
    especie: obj.especie,
    largo: obj.largo,
    ancho: obj.ancho,
    espesor: obj.espesor,
    cantidad: obj.cantidad,
    pies_tablares: obj.pies_tablares,//undefined
    observacion: obj.observacion, //undefined
    purchase_order_id: idPurchaseConcilation,
    fecha_conciliacion: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
};
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

not sure i get what you exactly want but why not try to put the ng-value for these variables ?

```
<td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pies_tablares" ng-value="table.pies_tablares" readonly>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="observacion" ng-value="table.observacion" readonly>
</td>
```